# Xaml file in other Xaml file

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am basically new to WPF.I have 2 Xaml files.

WpfCurrentSessionViewer.xaml and MainWindow.xaml.
Say WpfCurrentSessionViewer acts as a control which has labels in it.
MainWindow is the xaml where we need to inscribe the control.

Say in Asp.Net applications , we have an aspx page and a master page.
In similar way I need to do that as WpfCurrentSessionViewer.xaml acts as a master page
and MainWindow.xaml acts as an aspx page .

Regards,

Sachin K

Answer (score 1):

I think your question contradicts itself in terms of which way around the two controls are:

> Say WpfCurrentSessionViewer acts as a control which has labels in it. MainWindow is the xaml where we need to inscribe the control.
>
> WpfCurrentSessionViewer.xaml acts as a master page and MainWindow.xaml acts as an aspx page.

Either way, it sounds like you need to have one `Window` and one `UserControl` (or `CustomControl`, but if you're new to WPF you'll find a UserControl easier).

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is UI composition, or view composition. This is usually achieved in WPF with a `ContentControl` which has a `Content` property which you can set to any type, in your case, an instance of your `MainWindow` type.

I would consider adopting the [MVVM design pattern](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/04/14/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.aspx) when building WPF applications, and using an MVVM framework such as [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/), which makes view composition very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about frames ? There's a very good article about using frames here :
http://www.paulstovell.com/wpf-navigation